# Random Alert Noise from Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

Please tell me someone here can help with this I am going to lose my mind...

I have a new Alienware laptop. I am dual booting with linux and windows 10. The windows side is constantly throwing random alerts. The noise is the same one you get when you adjust the volume bar.

Steps I've Taken: 
- Ran all the troubleshooters, The audio one does throw me a warning about enhanced settings not working right and should be disabled but does not fix the problem.

- Checked drivers across the system everything seems ok

-Clean install

-CC cleaner reg repair

-malwarebytes scan

- Followed the advice presented [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/111412/how-to-find-out-which-program-a-default-beep-is-coming-from-in-windows-7)  Which talks about downloading the process monitor tool and then parsing for .wav files. Great plan!!!!  But... Whenever I run the tool the sound will not happen. Often it will happen just before and immediately after but it WILL NOT detect anything.

I finally gave in and decided to just disable all system notifications. But what do you know it still happens.

Im straight out of of ideas. Please someone help.

Comment: Have you checked out the event log? You may find some information in the "Application" log.

Comment: Also, have you tried running the Task Manager and killing all the processes one by one until you discover which one is causing it?

Comment: I have looked in the event log nothing stands out. And killing processes is not feasible because I cannot recreate it. I have noticed it is not happening as often at work so possibly a network connection notification. Not sure where to confirm that though

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't happen as often at work? Do you mean that you take the laptop at work and connect through there? If so, disable the WiFi and use the ethernet or vice versa?

Comment: Yeah good point. Ill try that later. The only reason I mention that is in one obscure post I read some user discovered that was his random beeping.

Comment: Update: So I'm about forty five minutes into ethernet test and so far so good. If the problem is the wifi dipping in and out, how in the hell do I disable that!!??

Comment: Does the issue occur after a full restart in Windows, with "fast startup" disabled? If not, then Linux may be corrupting the fast startup in memory (or in hiberfil.sys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the fact that if you connect the laptop via Ethernet the issue disappears, I bet this is a wifi interference issue, or a NIC compatibility issue. Try the steps below:

1) Change your home WiFi channel

2) Delete and re-install your wireless adapter

3) Uninstall and re-install your WiFi NIC drivers

4) Edit the properties of the wireless NIC to 802.11 b only or g only to see if it works

Comment: I did an Uninstall and reinstall of the nic last night and have not heard the noise yet!!!! I was wondering about the wifi channel now that I have a bunch of new neighbors so maybe they are not helping. I will mark this as the answer tomorrow if I still do not hear the noise. THANKYOU

Comment: I'm glad I could help