# Need to find out why RainMeter is triggering off the windows default noise (Windows Ding.wav)

Tags: windows-7, audio, system-sounds, rainmeter

I've been getting a windows default noise randomly. I'm on Win7.

I found this thread:
[How to find out which program a default beep is coming from in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/111412/how-to-find-out-which-program-a-default-beep-is-coming-from-in-windows-7)

I used Process Monitor and it looks like RainMeter desktop skin thing is doing it. I've had RainMeter for ages and it's only just started doing this.

Here's the stack (whatever that means) for the first "thing" in the list that triggered the noise:

"Frame","Module","Location","Address","Path"

"0","fltmgr.sys","FltAcquirePushLockShared + 0x5d7","0xfffff880012a30f7","C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys"

"1","fltmgr.sys","FltIsCallbackDataDirty + 0x24aa","0xfffff880012a5a0a","C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys"

"2","fltmgr.sys","FltReadFile + 0xeb53","0xfffff880012c12a3","C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys"

"3","ntoskrnl.exe","IoVerifyVolume + 0x16b2","0xfffff800039031b2","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"

"4","ntoskrnl.exe","RtlQueryDynamicTimeZoneInformation + 0xb14","0xfffff80003828fd4","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"

"5","ntoskrnl.exe","ObOpenObjectByName + 0x306","0xfffff80003713c56","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"

"6","ntoskrnl.exe","SePrivilegeCheck + 0x392","0xfffff80003723182","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"

"7","ntoskrnl.exe","longjmp + 0x5b93","0xfffff800034bbad3","C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"

"8","ntdll.dll","NtQueryAttributesFile + 0xa","0x77179c5a","C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll"

"9","KERNELBASE.dll","GetFileAttributesW + 0x78","0x7fefcfb2f58","C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll"

"10","winmm.dll","mmioOpenW + 0x2ccb","0x7fefb60e1eb","C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll"

"11","winmm.dll","mmioOpenW + 0x32ae","0x7fefb60e7ce","C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll"

"12","winmm.dll","winmm.dll + 0x11c0","0x7fefb6011c0","C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll"

"13","USER32.dll","TranslateMessageEx + 0x29d","0x77029bbd","C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll"

"14","USER32.dll","TranslateMessage + 0x1e2","0x770298c2","C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll"

"15","winmm.dll","winmm.dll + 0x110d","0x7fefb60110d","C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll"

"16","kernel32.dll","BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xd","0x76f0556d","C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll"

"17","ntdll.dll","RtlUserThreadStart + 0x1d","0x7716385d","C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll"

[Process Monitor Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anG71.jpg)

Does anyone know how to get RainMeter to stop triggering off this noise, please?.. If it would help to get Process Monitor to spew out some data or what-not just tell me how to do it. I updated Rainmeter BTW, but it didn't fix the problem.

Cheers

================================

Update

Awesome, thanks DBADon. 
I think that might have been it. Well, I checked the .ini and it looked like "Enable Chime" was already set to disabled. But then realised on that thread the gadget that was causing them problems is the same as the one I use. Checked the settings of the clock gadget and went to "Configure alarms", and "Enable Chime", "Enable Event Alarm", "Enable Alarm #1" and "Enable Alarm #2" were all ticked/enabled. Also I pressed to play the sounds from there and they all play that same windows default ding.wav.

I've un-ticked them all, and muted Rainmeter in the windows mixer as well. I think that's what might have caused the sound to start up in the first place - I probably un-muted it recently by mistake.

Thanks again, hopefully its sorted...

[Gadget Settings That Needed Changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5byf3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can disable the chime within the skin's INI file. This link explains a similar issue with Gadget's skin and how modifying the Digital Clock INI file resolved the issue. The setting you are looking for is "Enable Chime" and should be altered or deleted.

https://forum.rainmeter.net/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=27357&p=141987&hilit=chime#p141987

If you do not have the same skin, you should be able to find a similar setting in your skin's INI files.

Comment: Thanks DBADon, thats sorted it out I think.